# Restore backup error when execute Sql query from Code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am taking a backup of the existing database `RMHStore` at the specific path (`C:\ProgramData\RetailHero\DIAGTEST08TK5.bak`) creating a new database and restoring the backup on the newly created database.

The restore query works for another database except only one.

This is the query:

```
RESTORE DATABASE DIAGTestDiagnostics32416Jan202415723
FROM DISK = 'C:\ProgramData\RetailHero\DIAGTEST08TK5.bak' 
WITH MOVE 'DIAGTestDiagnostics32416Jan202415723' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQL2019\MSSQL\DATA\DIAGTestDiagnostics32416Jan202415723.mdf',
     MOVE 'DIAGTestDiagnostics32416Jan202415723_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQL2019\MSSQL\DATA\DIAGTestDiagnostics32416Jan202415723_log.ldf',
     RECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS = 10;
```

These are the errors I get:

> Msg 1834, Level 16, State 1, Line 61
> The file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQL2019\MSSQL\DATA\RMHSTORE.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'RMHSTORE'.
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 4, Line 61
> File 'RMHSTORE' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQL2019\MSSQL\DATA\RMHSTORE.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>
> Msg 1834, Level 16, State 1, Line 61
> The file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQL2019\MSSQL\DATA[RMHSTORE_log].ldf' cannot be overwritten. It is being used by database 'RMHSTORE'.
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 4, Line 61
> File 'RMHSTORE_log' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQL2019\MSSQL\DATA[RMHSTORE_log].ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>
> Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Line 61
> Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 61
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Sounds like the source database that was backed up has more than 2 files. What does `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\ProgramData\RetailHero\DIAGTEST08TK5.bak';` yield? You'll need a `MOVE` option for _all_ the files, not just the first two.

Comment: Also would be useful to know how the backup was created - if not `WITH INIT` then the `.bak` file could actually contain multiple backups, and you'll need to specify which one you want using `FILE = x`... the default is the first (oldest) file in the backup, not the most recent. (You can inspect using `RESTORE HEADERONLY`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the backup/restore documentation yet?

- [RESTORE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql#restoring_db_n_move_files)
- [RESTORE Statements - FILELISTONLY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql)

The problem here is that you cannot rename logical files while restoring backups - you can only move their physical location during the restore.

If you were to perform `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\ProgramData\RetailHero\DIAGTEST08TK5.bak'` I expect that it will contain only two logical files named `RMHSTORE` and `RMHSTORE_log`. So you would restore this backup using the following:

```sql
RESTORE DATABASE DIAGTestDiagnostics32416Jan202415723
FROM DISK = 'C:\ProgramData\RetailHero\DIAGTEST08TK5.bak' 
WITH MOVE 'RMHSTORE' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQL2019\MSSQL\DATA\DIAGTestDiagnostics32416Jan202415723.mdf',
     MOVE 'RMHSTORE_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQL2019\MSSQL\DATA\DIAGTestDiagnostics32416Jan202415723_log.ldf',
     RECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS = 10;
```

After restoring the backup, moving the files on disk while using those logical names, you can rename the logical files themselves on the server with something like the following:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE DIAGTestDiagnostics32416Jan202415723
MODIFY FILE (NAME=N'RMHSTORE', NEWNAME=N'DIAGTestDiagnostics32416Jan202415723');

ALTER DATABASE DIAGTestDiagnostics32416Jan202415723
MODIFY FILE (NAME=N'RMHSTORE_log', NEWNAME=N'DIAGTestDiagnostics32416Jan202415723_log');
```

See, [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) File and Filegroup Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options).